# Model Viewer API works for BIM 360 hub but not an ACC Hub?

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are running a custom application where we use the Forge OAuth as well as the Model Viewer APIs. The viewer is working against projects in BIM 360 but not against project in the newer ACC hubs.  Any reason for this? Our application identifies the model in the project (BIM 360 File URN) and then the Revit element GUID.  Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Updates:**

It was caused by an incorrect URN and another Forge Help agent has helped resolve the problem.

==========

I had you raise a Forge Help ticket, and replied to you. It sounds like you forgot to set up the custom integrations for your ACC account. Please follow the instruction here to provision your client id in ACC.

https://petrbroz.github.io/forge-samples-docs/docs/intro/#provision-access-in-other-products

Comment: Please, refer to this link (same resource Eason posted): https://forge-tutorials.autodesk.io/#provision-access-in-other-products

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue lied with having an incorrect configuration for the Forge Viewer. The app was already over 2 years old, and used an old method to load OTG (SVF2) files using the so-called 'fluent' API, which apparently only still worked for BIM360, not ACC.

I had the following:

```
var options = {
    env: 'FluentProduction',
    api: 'fluent', // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'streamingV2_EU'
};
```

Which should be:

```
var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
    api: 'streamingV2', // for EU/EMEA change to 'streamingV2_EU'
};
```

Or, if you want the SVF2 format:

```
var options = {
    env: 'MD20ProdEU',
    api: 'D3S', // for EU/EMEA change to 'streamingV2_EU'
};
```

Sources: [Autodesk Tutorial](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/initialization/) & [Autodesk Blog Post](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/svf2-public-beta-new-optimized-viewer-format)